# ImportError: No module named cqlengine, but worked on python command

Tags: python, cassandra, scrapy

I am new in python.
I have a scrapy project. I am using conda virtual environment where I have written a pipeline class like this:

```
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table, create_keyspace_network_topology
from recentnews.cassandra.model.NewsPaperDataModel import NewspaperDataModel

from recentnews.common.Constants import DEFAULT_KEYSPACE


class RecentNewsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        connection.setup(["192.168.99.100"], DEFAULT_KEYSPACE, protocol_version=3, port=9042)
        create_keyspace_network_topology(DEFAULT_KEYSPACE, {'DC1': 2})
        sync_table(NewspaperDataModel)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        NewspaperDataModel.create(
            title=item.title,
            url=item.url,
            domain=item.domain
        )
        return item
```

When I run the scrapy crawler like `scrapy crawl author`, it gives me this error:

```
(news) (C:\Miniconda2\envs\news) E:\Shoshi\Python Projects\recentnews-scrapy\recentnews>scrapy crawl author
2017-05-31 15:56:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: recentnews)
2017-05-31 15:56:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'recentnews.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['recentnews.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'recentnews'}
2017-05-31 15:56:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-05-31 15:56:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-31 15:56:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-05-31 15:56:30 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2017-05-31 15:56:30 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 95, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 77, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 102, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "E:\Shoshi\Python Projects\recentnews-scrapy\recentnews\recentnews\pipelines.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
ImportError: No module named cqlengine
```

I am using conda virtual environment.

But, when I run this code from python command line it works fine. no error:

```
(news) (C:\Miniconda2\envs\news) E:\Shoshi\Python Projects\recentnews-scrapy\recentnews>python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
>>> from cassandra.cqlengine.management import sync_table, create_keyspace_network_topology
>>> from recentnews.cassandra.model.NewsPaperDataModel import NewspaperDataModel
>>> from recentnews.common.Constants import DEFAULT_KEYSPACE
>>> connection.setup(["192.168.99.100"], DEFAULT_KEYSPACE, protocol_version=3, port=9042)
>>> create_keyspace_network_topology(DEFAULT_KEYSPACE, {'DC1': 2})
C:\Miniconda2\envs\news\lib\site-packages\cassandra\cqlengine\management.py:545: UserWarning: CQLENG_ALLOW_SCHEMA_MANAGEMENT environment variable is not set. Future versions of this package will require this variable to enable management functions.
  warnings.warn(msg)
>>> sync_table(NewspaperDataModel)
......
```

You can see that `from cassandra.cqlengine import connection` is imported perfectly.
What am I missing? Why not this code is working when I run this using `scrapy crawl author`?

Comment: `from cassandra.cqlengine import connection` is on line 7. What are the statements before that line? what happens if you call `python recentnews/pipelines.py`? is there a module called `cassandra.py` somewhere in your scrapy project?

Comment: @paultrmbrth: before line 7 there are some autogenerated lines, which are commented. I will let you know about `python recentnews/pipelines.py`

Comment: @paultrmbrth: same error. 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "recentnews/pipelines.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
ImportError: No module named cqlengine`

Comment: What about my other question:  is there a module called `cassandra.py` somewhere in your scrapy project?

Comment: no, there is no module called `cassandra.py` in my project

Comment: You can also add something like `import cassandra; print(dir(cassandra))` at the beginning of your `pipelines.py` to check if you're importing the package you want. `cassandra.__file__` may help too

Comment: ok, let me try.

Comment: @paultrmbrth: Thank you very much. there was a folder in my project named `cassandra`. using `import cassandra; print(dir(cassandra.__file__))` I was able to get that import was trying to get cqlengine from my project folder. I changed that folder name and everything works fine. Thank you. Please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appeared that [there was a folder named `recentnews/cassandra/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44282257/importerror-no-module-named-cqlengine-but-worked-on-python-command?noredirect=1#comment75573040_44282257) in the OP's scrapy project (namespace `recentnews.cassandra`).

When scrapy imports the item pipeline class `recentnews.pipelines.RecentNewsPipeline`, `importlib`'s interpreting of `from cassandra.cqlengine import connection` (at the beginning of `recentnews/pipeline.py`) found the local `recentnews.cassandra` module before the virtualenv-installed `cassandra` package.

One way to check which module is being imported is to add `import cassandra; print(cassandra.__file__)` before the `import` statement that fails.

Comment: that was really helpful for newbe like me. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

When you create a virtual environment, by default the user-installed packages are not copied. You would therefore have to run `pip install casandra` (or whatever the package is called) in your virtual environment. That will probably fix this problem.

Comment: cassandra is already installed in my virtual environment. and all the command given in the question is run fro virtual environment.

Comment: OK. That's not it then. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I am new in python. can you give me any suggestion about this error?